# Vertically aligning a FontAwesome Icon with text witnin an a-tag

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

What is the best way of vertically aligning a FontAwesome Icon to vertically align with the text in a, `<a href>` tag?

Here is the HTML along with the CSS I have so far.

Thanks.

```css
.btn-tertiary{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 7px 10px 10px;
 border: 2px #E0DDDD solid;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #0D0155;
 height: auto;
 font-weight: 600;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 -webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.btn-tertiary:hover{
 background-color: #004;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: solid 2px #004;
}
.btn-tertiary i{
 color: #E0DDDD!important;
 float: right!important;
 font-size:20px;
 height: 20px;
 vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
<a class="btn-tertiary" title="Login to mange your investmnts & more" href="#">Login to my account<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use paddings for your i element. Or make a element position relative, and i position absolute. And then use top or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is with a little extra markup:

```
<a class="foo">
  <span>The text you want to align</span>

  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</a>
```

Then add some CSS that will set `vertical-align` to `middle` for both `span` and `i`.

```
.foo span,
.foo i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Obviously this is a contrived example, but you should be able to update your code based on it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, all you have to do is tweak `line-height` for the `i` element.

```
line-height: 17px;
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.btn-tertiary{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 7px 10px 10px;
 border: 2px #E0DDDD solid;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #0D0155;
 height: auto;
 font-weight: 600;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 -webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.btn-tertiary:hover{
 background-color: #004;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: solid 2px #004;
}
.btn-tertiary i{
 color: #E0DDDD!important;
 float: right!important;
 font-size:20px;
 /*height: 20px;*/
 vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="btn-tertiary" title="Login to mange your investmnts & more" href="#">Login to my account<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```